# C simple string program does not compile

Tags: c, string, strlen

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char Jones(char, char);

int main() {
    char name[]="Andrew";
    char surname[]="Jones";
    char result[80];
    result=Jones(name, surname);
    puts(result);
    return 0;
}

char Jones(char name, char surname)
{
    char result[80];
    int length;
    length = strlen(surname);
    for (int i=0; i<50; i++) 
    {
        result[length+i] = name[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

The program does not compile and i dont know why. It is supposed to read two strings and swap their places. It should display eg. "Jones Andrew".

Comment: What does the compiler say? Always include compiler output with these kinds of questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one problem:

```
char name[]="Andrew";
char surname[]="Jones";
char result[80];
wynik=Jones(name, surname);
```

This calls `Jones()` with character arrays (which will decay to character pointers), but the function is declared to accept single characters only.

You should change the function to take `char *name, char *surname`, since it really does seem to expect strings.

Further, you can't return a character array like you're doing in `Jones()`, you need to read up quite a bit on how to work with strings in C.

Also, `wynik` looks undeclared, that'll also make it fail to build.

Comment: Wynik should be result. I've made a mintakie when translating to English.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few errors:

```
char Jones(char, char);
```

This takes just a single char, not a char * which you need for a string.

`result=Jones(name, surname);`

Here result is an array. In C, you cannot assign to an array.

```
char Jones(char name, char surname)
{ char result[80];
...
return result;
}
```

Here you return `result` which is a local variable. But to return a string, you'd need to return a char*. But that char* would point to a local variable within the Jones function, which is no longer valid when the function ends. One solution is to pass in a buffer where you write the result that the caller owns.
Your algorithm for combining the surename and name is also wrong, you never do anything with the surename.

You'll need to do this:

```
char *Jones(char*, char* , char *);

int main() {
  char name[]="Andrew";
  char surname[]="Jones";
  char result[80];
  char *p;
  p = Jones(name, surname, result);
  puts(p);
  return 0;
}

char *Jones(char *name, char *surname, char *result)
{ 
  int length;
  int i,k;
  length = strlen(surname);
  for (i=0; i<length ; i++) 
  {
    result[i] = surname[i];
  }
  result[i++] = ' '; //add a space

  length = strlen(name);
  for (k=0; k<length ; k++, i++) 
  {
    result[i] = name[k];
  }    
 result[i] = 0; //add nul terminator to end the string
 return result;
}
```

The conatenation could be simplified in many ways, e.g. to

```
strcpy(result, surename);
strcat(result, " ");
strcat(result, name);
```

or the Jones function could just do:

```
 sprintf(result, "%s %s", surename, name);
```

In all cases, the function is rather fragile, as it's easy to overflow the result buffer if you pass in something else that does not fit within the `result` buffer.

Comment: But i want this second function to return the string.

Comment: @user1828352 changed it to return result. But this is C, so you are responsible for deciding where the storage space for all your stuff are. I've decided to store the resulting string in the `result` array in main().

Comment: But i wantthe function to copy it sign by sign and not by strcpy

Comment: @user1828352 The code I show does that, it copies it character by character. That's what the 2 loops inside `Jones()` does. If you don't want to use strcpy as suggested near the bottom of the answer, then don't use that.

Answer (score 0):

1) The `name` and `surname` are char array and not single char so you have to change the input parameters types of your function `Jones()` the input parameters types should be `char name[]` (char array) or `char *name` (pointer to array of char)

2) You can not return an array defined locally and statically in the function. and if you want to return a string from the function, the string should be constant or it should be a buffer allocated dynamically (with `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc`) into the function And for both cases the function type should be `char *Jonas()` and not `char Jonas()`

Or you can pass the `result` array via input parametr. and in this case you can fill it into the function.

```
void Jones(char *name, char *surname, char *result)
```

and in the main:

```
char result[80];
Jones(names, surname, result);
```

3) The following `for` loop is missing some thing

```
for (int i=0; i<50; i++) 
{
   result[length+i] = name[i];
}
```

The `result` elements from element `0` to element `length` are containing garbage because the `result` array is not initiated. so when you `printf` the `result` array you will get garbages printed. You have to initiate elements between `0` to `length` in the `result` array

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* Jones(char*, char*);

int main() {
char name[]="Andrew";
char surname[]="Jones";
puts(Jones(name,surname));
return 0;
}

char* Jones(char *name, char *surname)
{
    strcat(surname," ");
    strcat(surname,name);
    return surname;
}
```